# My jQuery works in JSFiddle, but not on my website! What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

Help!  I'm trying to work on a project where the the content shrinks to 0, changes, then slides open again to the right size of the new content.  I have it all working properly on JSFiddle, but it will NOT work on my website!!  I'm using exactly the same jQuery, CSS, and HTML in both places. and I *DID* remember to call the current version of jQuery (jquery-2.2.1.min.js) on my website.

Here's the working copy on JSFiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/sy7e7hge

Here's the non-working copy on my site:

> http://goo.gl/3iVn2E

The mouseover change works just fine on both, but the clicking to change size does not do anything on my website!

Here is the stackoverflow snippet (which also works)!

```js
function change() {
  $("#inner").animate({height: "hide"});
  $('.content').delay(399).fadeOut(0);
  $("#inner").animate({height: "show"}, 1000);
};

$("#menu_home").click(function() {
  change();
  $('#home').fadeIn(0);
});

$("#menu_page01").click(function() {
  change();
  $('#page01').fadeIn(0);
});

$("#menu_page02").click(function() {
  change();
  $('#page02').fadeIn(0);
});
```

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#outer {
  background: green;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 15px;
}

#inner {
  background: orange;
  width: 500px;
  height: 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">

      <div class="content" id="home">HOME<br>HOME<br>HOME</div>
      <div class="content" id="page01" style="display: none;">PAGE 1<br>PAGE 1<br>PAGE 1<br>PAGE 1<br>PAGE 1<br>PAGE 1<br>PAGE 1<br>PAGE 1</div>
      <div class="content" id="page02" style="display: none;">PAGE 2<br>PAGE 2<br>PAGE 2<br>PAGE 2<br>PAGE 2<br>PAGE 2</div>
      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="menu" id="menu_home" onmouseover="this.bgColor='black'; this.style.color='red'" onmouseout="this.bgColor='white'; this.style.color='black'">click to show home page</div>
<br><br>
<div class="menu" id="menu_page01" onmouseover="this.bgColor='black'; this.style.color='red'" onmouseout="this.bgColor='white'; this.style.color='black'">click to show page 1</div>
<br><br>
<div class="menu" id="menu_page02" onmouseover="this.bgColor='black'; this.style.color='red'" onmouseout="this.bgColor='white'; this.style.color='black'">click to show page 2</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?!  What do I need to do to get it working on my website?

Comment: You need to put the jQuery code of your website in a document.ready handler; `$(function() { /* your code here... */ })`. jsFiddle does this automatically, hence why it works.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't remember ever doing that before!  But putting `$(function() {` once at the beginning and `})` once at the end did the trick!!  I took a look back at my older projects, which were actually much more complicated, and my jQuery `.js` file didn't have that -- just each individual function!

Comment: I added an example for you, check my answer. The document.ready handler is always required if you add your script in the `<head>` of the document. If you put it just before the `</body>` tag then you don't need it as the DOM will have loaded by that point.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the jQuery code of your website in a document.ready handler. jsFiddle does this automatically, hence why it works already. Try this:

```
function change() {
    $("#inner").animate({ height: "hide" });
    $('.content').delay(399).fadeOut(0);
    $("#inner").animate({ height: "show" }, 1000);
};

$(function() {
    $("#menu_home").click(function() {
        change();
        $('#home').fadeIn(0);
    });

    $("#menu_page01").click(function() {
        change();
        $('#page01').fadeIn(0);
    });

    $("#menu_page02").click(function() {
        change();
        $('#page02').fadeIn(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any practical difference between this way, the way suggested by Bhushan Kawadkar below, and the way suggested by 'trincot' (which was just to put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js.js"></script>` before the `</body>` tag and not change anything in the `.js` file?

Comment: The difference between this and Bhushan's answer is the scope of the `change()` function. With my version it's accessible anywhere, with his it's only available within the document.ready handler. The behaviour of mine and trincot's answers are identical, only the implementation changes.

Answer (score 2):

Move this line of your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js.js"></script>
```

To just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js.js"></script>
</body>
```

And you'll be fine.

Like you had it, the document is not yet built, and elements like `inner` do not exist yet, so the JavaScript code does not attach events to them.

#### Notes

The other `script` tag (jQuery) does not need any particular element in the document to execute. So for that `script` tag it makes perfect sense to keep it in the `head` tag.

Others suggested to wrap the code in `$(document).ready(function(){ .. })` or in `$(function() { .. })`. This works too. It makes your code execute at slightly different times. If you would implement code in all three ways, the order of execution would be:

1. code following my suggestion
2. code in `$(function() { .. })`
3. code in `$(document).ready(function(){ .. })`

In some cases (1) -- or in rare cases even (2) -- can be too soon for code to execute as intended, but in your case method (1) is fine: you can attach event handlers as soon as the elements are created.

Examples where (1) *may* be too soon is when you want to get the position of an element, reposition it or resize it, set the focus on another element,  ... etc.

Comment: That makes complete sense!  But why is the `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>` still ok to be in the `<head>`??

Comment: And s there any practical difference between THIS way and the ways suggested by Rory McCrossan and Bhushan Kawadkar below?

Comment: I added explanations in my answer about those two questions.

Comment: Did the explanations answer your question about the differences?

Answer (score 1):

After viewing source code of your webside, I have found that you forgot to mention below code in your html. Please add below code in `document.ready` block as show below

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 function change() {
    $("#inner").animate({height: "hide"});
    $('.content').delay(399).fadeOut(0);
    $("#inner").animate({height: "show"}, 1000);
  };

  $("#menu_home").click(function() {
    change();
    $('#home').fadeIn(0);
  });

  $("#menu_page01").click(function() {
    change();
     $('#page01').fadeIn(0);
  });

  $("#menu_page02").click(function() {
    change();
    $('#page02').fadeIn(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there any practical difference between this way, the way suggested by Rory McCrossan above, and the way suggested by 'trincot' (which was just to put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js.js"></script>` before the `</body>` tag and not change anything in the `.js` file?